# Пустить весь трафик на определенный порт через другой хост

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, faq

Есть следующая схема:

HOSTA
HOSTB
HOSTC

HOSTC на порту 80 принимает соединения от HOSTA но не принимает от HOSTB

Нужно, чтобы все запросы от HOSTB к HOSTC шли через HOSTA

Какие правила в iptables мне нужно добавить на HOSTA и HOSTB чтобы обеспечить такую схему?

На HOSTB добавил следующее правило:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d <HOSTA> -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Что нужно сделать дальше?

Comment: одними только правилами *netfilter*-а не обойтись: на машине hosta надо будет ещё и разрешить «форвардинг» пакетов. p.s. *На HOSTB добавил* — вероятно, имелся ввиду hosta, а не hostb?

Comment: В sysctl.conf прописал 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1

Comment: Добавил именно на HOSTB, или это не верно?

Comment: выше у вас написано, что hostb — «начальная» точка, а не промежуточная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**обозначения**:

- *машина1* с *ip1* — та, на которой формируется трафик;
- *машина2* с *ip2* — та, которая служит промежуточной точкой и имеет только один сетевой интерфейс;
- *машина3* с *ip3* — та, которая служит конечной точкой.
- *порт* — номер порта, который и подвергаем манипуляциям

---

**инструкция:**

1. на *машине1* надо подменять в исходящем трафике *ip3* на *ip2*. примерно так:

   ```
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d ip3 --dport порт -j DNAT --to-destination ip2
   ```
2. на *машине2* надо разрешить «форвардинг» пакетов. например, так:

   ```
   $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
3. на *машине2* надо подменять обращения с *машниы1* (на требуемый *порт*) на обращения к *машине3*:

   ```
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s ip1 --dport порт -j DNAT --to-destination ip3
   ```
4. на *машине2* надо подменять адрес источника (*ip1*) уходящих пакетов на адрес самой *машины2*:

   ```
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s ip1 --dport порт -j SNAT --to-source ip2
   ```