# Перенаправление трафика на другой IP

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, iptables, маршрутизация

День добрый. Имеется VPS на дебиан где-то в интернете с IP `IP_VPS` с единственным интерфейсом, и сервер с внешним IP `IP_SERVER` на который хочу перенаправлять трафик, пришедший на `IP_VPS`.

Пытаюсь настроить правило iptables на VPS так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dst IP_VPS --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination IP_SERVER:80
```

но пакеты до `IP_SERVER` не доходят (проверял wireshark). Я что-то упустил или iptables в принципе не работает таким образом?

Comment: Что дает `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` ? должно быть `1`

Comment: выдало 0. что бы это значило?

Comment: посмотрите `/etc/sysctl.conf` если такой в вашей системе есть то надо там включить ip_forward. Если нет - то где нибудь в файлах загрузки написать `echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` без этого машина никуда не будет отправлять никакие пакеты, которые на нее пришли (а не родились на ней самой)

Comment: на `/etc/sysctl.conf` пишет Permission denied, включил через `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` Вообще, я почитал что ip_forward перенаправляет пакеты с одного интерфейса на другой, это значит их должно быть минимум 2 и одним не обойтись?

Comment: [то же самое](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440216/178576), только без *машины1*.

Comment: ну в фразе "с одного интерфейса на другой" слово "другой" вполне может быть и тем же самым интерфейсом :)

Comment: всем огромное спасибо, инструкция от @alexanderbarakin помогла (видимо SNAT был обязателен)

Comment: кстати, на клиентском компе все равно через wireshark палятся ip конечного сервера, после первых пакетов на `IP_VPS`. Полностью его спрятать таким образом без прокси я так понимаю не получится?